# How can I reinstall Network Manager after uninstalling it?

Tags: networking, centos, networkmanager

I am running a version of RHCE6 on my laptop, and lately I've been trying various stuff about network configuration through command line. Last night, I tried removing the NetworkManager using

```
yum remove NetworkManager
```

from the system, so that I could have more control of the network through the command line. But the result is, I didn't manage to configure the wireless connection through `wpa_supplicant` , and I need wireless connection during my travel.
I tried to reinstall using :

```
yum install NetworkManager
```

Some version installed, but I didn't get an icon in the taskbar, and of course, the network doesn't work. The package I previously removed (about 24MB) was much larger that the one I just installed(about 2MB), I think some dependencies must be missing.

How could I Reinstall network manager correctly to restore my connectivity?

Answer (score 1):

To identify discrepancy in packages removed/installed, you can check `/var/log/yum.log*`.  Scroll back to where NetworkManager is removed, and look at all the packages removed with the same datestamp (removed because they depended on NetworkManager).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try bringing up your network 'by hand'?
This is easiest if you can be connected by a ethernet cable (non-wireless) just long enough to reinstall Networkmanager. Then it is likely a simple matter of (as 'root', of course):

```
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

If it simply must be via wireless there is a command-line formula which goes:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -Dwext && dhclient wlan0
```

Note your driver maybe be other than 'wext'; and all this presumes that you have /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf already set-up.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I hit this problem recently and the answers here helped.   I will expand and say when you reinstall NM try:

`yum install NetworkManager*`

That will pickup the ui packages needed for the applet.

When I parsed my yum logs I found this:

```
Jun 16 18:54:43 Erased: NetworkManager-gnome
Jun 16 18:54:43 Erased: NetworkManager-openconnect
Jun 16 18:54:44 Erased: NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the [Wiki page for NetworkManager](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Laptops/NetworkManager)

Install :

```
yum install NetworkManager
```

Check if running or Start if not:

```
service NetworkManager status
```

Start if it's not running:

```
service NetworkManager start
chkconfig NetworkManager on
```

Disable network and wpa_supp services as stated in Wiki:

```
chkconfig network off
chkconfig wpa_supplicant off
```

And Reboot.
To open it's GUI:

```
nm-applet
nm-connection-editor
```

***UPDATE 1***:Check out **[Reinstall all dependencies of a given package?](https://superuser.com/questions/338296/how-to-use-yum-to-reinstall-all-dependencies-of-a-given-package)**

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've run all the commands you listed, still no avail. Opening the GUI using `nm-applet` and `nm-connection-editor` would return "command not found".

Comment: Check with `yum whatprovides */nm-applet` and `yum whatprovides */nm-connection-editor` what packages you need to install as well.

Comment: @YangJy Updated my answer.

Comment: @alexanderJanssen thank you for the comment, as now I have no Internet access on the laptop in question, I'll check your commands later. :)

Comment: @xperator Thank you again, it really helps :)

Comment: @YangYi, you can install the package containing a file (a program in this case) by `yum install /usr/bin/nm-applet` (or perhaps just `/bin/nm-applet`). You can give it a list of several files to process at once too.